# AHBottomNavigation Not Changing Color Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to implement the bottom navigation bar, using the AHBottomNavigation library at: https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation

The color of my navigation bar doesn't change - the ripple effect happens, and the text is perfect. My app bar stays one color. Here is the code:

```
public void initializeNavigationBar()
{
    menuItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
    bottomNavigation = (AHBottomNavigation) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_bar);
    menuItemsList.add(new AHBottomNavigationItem("Home", R.drawable.home, R.color.colorPrimary));
    menuItemsList.add(new AHBottomNavigationItem("View Profile", R.drawable.person_profile, R.color.colorPrimary));
    menuItemsList.add(new AHBottomNavigationItem("Map a Route", R.drawable.route, R.color.colorPrimary));
    menuItemsList.add(new AHBottomNavigationItem("Start Run", R.drawable.start_run, R.color.colorPrimary));
    bottomNavigation.addItems(menuItemsList);
    bottomNavigation.setAccentColor(Color.parseColor("#FF5722"));
    bottomNavigation.setInactiveColor(Color.parseColor("#FF5722"));
    bottomNavigation.setColored(true);
    bottomNavigation.setForceTint(true);
    bottomNavigation.setCurrentItem(0);
    bottomNavigation.setBehaviorTranslationEnabled(false);
    bottomNavigation.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    bottomNavigation.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(int position, boolean wasSelected) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            AthleteLandingFragment homeScreen = new AthleteLandingFragment();
            FragmentTransaction homeTransaction = mgr.beginTransaction();
            homeTransaction.replace(R.id.MainActivityContentArea, homeScreen,
                    "AthleteLandingFragment");
            homeTransaction.addToBackStack("AthleteLandingFragment");
            toolbarTextView.setText("Athlete Landing Screen");
            homeTransaction.commit();
            break;
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I want the bar to be blue. I tried using setDefaultBackgroundColor and that didn't work.

Please help

Comment: hey, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same problem and I have got the solution as well:

bottomNavigation.setColored(false);

please use the code mentioned above for the problem, it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

I know you probably figured it out by now, but for anyone else struggling with the save thing, the problem is the R.color.colorPrimary:

```
menuItemsList.add(new AHBottomNavigationItem("Home", R.drawable.home, R.color.colorPrimary));
menuItemsList.add(new AHBottomNavigationItem("View Profile", R.drawable.person_profile, R.color.colorPrimary));
menuItemsList.add(new AHBottomNavigationItem("Map a Route", R.drawable.route, R.color.colorPrimary));
menuItemsList.add(new AHBottomNavigationItem("Start Run", R.drawable.start_run, R.color.colorPrimary));
```

If you want the whole navigation bar to change to a specific color, you must replace the colorPrimary by that specific color. In this way when the tab is tapped, the whole nav bar will change to that color. E.g. R.color.RED

Answer (score 0):

Hey can you change your like this :

```
    navigationHome = new AHBottomNavigationItem(getResources().getString(R.string.home), R.drawable.ic_home);
    navigationWishlist = new AHBottomNavigationItem(getResources().getString(R.string.wishlist), R.drawable.ic_wishlist);
    navigationAccount = new AHBottomNavigationItem(getResources().getString(R.string.account), R.drawable.ic_account);

    bottomNavigation.addItem(navigationHome);
    bottomNavigation.addItem(navigationWishlist);
    bottomNavigation.addItem(navigationAccount);

    bottomNavigation.setAccentColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
```

this code worked for me

Answer (score -1):

This code worked for me:

```
bottomNavigation.setColored(true);
```

My items color changing with every click.